# Vim :w hangs prompting "writing"

Tags: vim

I have a .html file that hangs when I try to save my changes.
The changes get saved but vim goes haywire.

Here is a screenshot (I pressed enter a few time):

[image: screenshot]

If I try to save it again
[image: screenshot2]

Any ideas ?

*EDIT 1*
I "solved" this by deleting the file and folder and recreated them. Don't know what was wrong with it.

Comment: This appears to have something to do with the first line being <!DOCTYPE html>.

Comment: It looks like something is checking the syntax of your file on write.

Comment: you have `syntastic` plugin installed, haven't u?

Comment: yes, I have `syntastic`. It came with carlhuda/janus. I have tried upgrading it manually from 3.0.0 to 3.3.0. I have also tried disabling it. I have also upgraded janus. This only happens to this one file. and if I remove <!DOCTYPE html> it works fine. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the [same issue with an XML file](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/issues/1150). The problem comes from Syntastic which queries w3.org to get the DTD for the file. When w3.org is down, this happens. To prevent the problem from appearing you need to clone [this repo](https://github.com/darcyparker/XMLCatalog) locally and add this to your `.bash_profile`:

```
XML_CATALOG_FILES=/path/to/XMLCatalog/catalog.xml
export XML_CATALOG_FILES
```

P.S: You didn't fix the issue by recreating the file and the folder.